# Wait for an async method to finish

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

i am writing a node js function which unzip a file and further read the unzipped files to process further. The problem is, before the file gets unzipped asynchronously, the read function gets started and it fails with file not found error. please suggest possible way to wait for unzip process before read file triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, i have got it working with following code -

```
fs.createReadStream('master.zip')
.pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'gitdownloads/repo' }))
.on('close', function () {
...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here :

https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

Node Hero - Understanding Async Programming in Node.js

This is the third post of the tutorial series called Node Hero - in these chapters you can learn how to get started with Node.js and deliver software products using it.

In this chapter, I’ll guide you through async programming principles, and show you how to do async in JavaScript and Node.js.

Comment: If you find helpfull please mark as answer or upvote please

Answer (score 0):

**Async library(http://caolan.github.io/async/)**

This library is used in order to control the execusion of the functions you have.

For example:

```
async.series({
    unzip: function(callback) {
        unzip('package.zip', function(err, data) {
            if(!err)
               callback(null, data);
        });
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    // results is now equal to: {unzip: data}
    readingUnzipFiles(...);
});
```

Here readingUnzipFiles is executed once the unzip task calls the callback funcion.

**Promisses**

Another solution would be use a promisse module like Q(https://github.com/kriskowal/q):

```
function unzip(fileName, outputPath) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    fs.createReadStream(fileName)
       .pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: outputPath }))
       .on('end', function(){
           deferred.resolve(result);
       });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then you could use the function like:

```
unzip('file.zip', '/output').then(function() {
    processZipFiles();
});
```

Comment: .Thanks. My unzip function writes many files to file system and i want to read them to process only after all have been written. can this be solved with above example ?

Comment: i am using fs.writeFile() function to write each file. is their a way to get a callback when all files have been written. thanks

Comment: Can you update your code implementation to take a look?

Comment: which post? I cant see it

Comment: look in the answers section.